# Messed up bootloaders windows 10 and Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot

So i wanted to dual boot windows 10 and ubuntu. Ended up using different boots for for both. long story boot loaders got corrupted or something. no windows recovery no ubuntu recovery. i have looked everywhere and tried everything. i am currently on a ubuntu pendrive. i need to keep whats on both sides as i cant get some of the things stored. anyway to delete all bootloaders and remake them myself?

Comment: Don't delete your bootloaders.  In what mode was Windows installed (UEFI or legacy)? What mode was Ubuntu installed?  Which mode is selected from your UEFI settings (formerly known as BIOS).   The EFI menu (some function key at power-on) offers devices/oses to boot -- can you boot anything that way?

Comment: ok so i changed it, not knowing what i was thinking, i had it changed to legacy and boot to legacy then changed it back....thats when everything went wrong. windows is uefi. i have access to both from my pendrive. i am currently installing a new ubuntu on aanother partition to maybe try and get the other to boot'

Comment: sorry didnt answer the last part, i can access bios and boot from usb thats it. i have windows 10 and ubuntu 16.04 installed. any way you know i can make fresh bootloader entries i am super new to this

Comment: What's (left) on the disk?  In a terminal run sudo blkid  and see what partitions you have on your hard disk.  Determine if an "EFI system partition" exists, and if the Windows partition exists.  Maybe the forums is a better place to get this fixed: https://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=333   Mount the EFI partition and see if the bootloaders .../EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgvw.efi and .../EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi exist.  All you may need to do is add pointers to them with efibootmgr if they exist.

Comment: Everything is here just not loading had Ubuntu up and running this mooring then tried fixing Windows not with iso and Ubuntu and subdued don't not now I'm running rescatux and super grub disk to try and delete some entries, got to many no way to upload the logs, using phone to boot images.

Comment: What I did to get Ubuntu working was in rescue grub pointed the boot to sda2, where I was moving the boot to fix. Then it went back to sda5 where the system is installed

Comment: OK so confirmed Ubuntu is on sda2,I just fell in love with super grub disk. Do how do I get Ubuntu to look there permanently? And on to try Windows

Answer (score 0):

If you can run Ubuntu, start a terminal (ctrl alt t) and run

```
sudo update-grub
```

to fix the grub menu.

It's not clear to me if you even have grub running, so if not, take a look at the efi boot entries with:

```
sudo efibootmgr -v
```

and if you don't have an ubuntu entry with shimx64.efi or grubx64.efi, make one, and put that entry first in the bootorder.  See the manual pages for efibootmgr:

```
man efibootmgr
```

for adding entries or changing the bootorder.

---

That efibootmgr output indicates that you are running Ubuntu in legacy mode, regardless of the fact that your machine is capable of UEFI mode.  The install media boots both ways, depending upon the firmware settings you select in the UEFI/BIOS settings.  If you post the link to the boot-repair output (just the report, no fixes yet), that will help, but there are already lots of answers about fixing an install in the wrong mode.

Comment: ok idk if its good or bad but.... i get this when running that command

myster_p@Myster:~$ sudo efibootmgr
[sudo] password for myster_p: 
efibootmgr: EFI variables are not supported on this system.
myster_p@Myster:~$

Comment: I know its efi tho cause thats where my images are..sorry dont know how to make it all fancy lol

myster_p@Myster:~$ ls /boot
abi-4.8.0-36-generic         lost+found
abi-4.8.0-49-generic         memtest86+.bin
config-4.8.0-36-generic      memtest86+.elf
config-4.8.0-49-generic      memtest86+_multiboot.bin
efi                          System.map-4.8.0-36-generic
grub                         System.map-4.8.0-49-generic
grub.bak                     vmlinuz-4.8.0-36-generic
initrd.img-4.8.0-36-generic  vmlinuz-4.8.0-49-generic
initrd.img-4.8.0-49-generic
myster_p@Myster:~$

Comment: Absolutely, just need to get to WiFi lol

Comment: Bro I'm sorry it's been a hectic week. I just got rid of windows cleaning up the mess then ill upload that